# Date difference showing wrong result :past feb 2021 why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, locale

```
var d1 = new Date("05/02/2021");   
var d2 = new Date("31/12/2021");   
    
var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();   
    
var daydiff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Here the date difference comes to 332 while it is 329... Any reason why?

Comment: `d2` is invalid date, you should have format `MM/DD/YYYY`

Comment: When I convert the dates to `mm/dd/yyyy` I get 329 as expected

Comment: @DominikMatis Yes, If when returning it returns `null`, and your @yusuffk your final variable returns `NaN`

Comment: @Nick I am having 243, when I convert the dates to `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Did you convert the first date too? It should be `02/05/2021`

Comment: @Nick No, Fixed! Thanks I was facing this same to same problem yesterday with different dates.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const date1 = new Date('2/05/2021');
const date2 = new Date('12/31/2021');
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milliseconds");
console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

Try changing the format of the date

```
const date1 = new Date('2/05/2021');
const date2 = new Date('12/31/2021');
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milliseconds");
console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

hope, this solves your problem.